# Stripping Metadata Info of the uploaded file

Tags: .net, angular, security, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I am using Angular and Web API in the backend.

I have a functionality of uploading the file (mainly docx, xlxs,jpg, png pdf formats) from Angular application and same can be downloaded by others in other screen of the application.

I got comment from security team to strip the metadata info of the uploaded file.

[image]

[image]

The code i am using to upload in Angular and Web API -

```
 <input type="file" name="input-attach-doc" id="input-attach-doc" accept=".pdf, .jpeg, .png" 
(change)="addFiles($event)" multiple #inputAttachments />


addFiles(event) {
    let files: FileList = event.target.files
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, (file) => {
        if (file.size > '5242880') {
            this.notificationService.showWarning('Incorrect file size. Please choose a file with less than 5 MB.',
                'Warning!');
        }
        else {
            if (file.type == 'image/png' || file.type == 'image/jpeg' || file.type == 'application/pdf') {
                this.attachedDocs.push(file)
            }
            else {
                this.notificationService.showWarning('Incorrect file type selected. Please choose a pdf,png or jpeg file.',
                    'Warning!');
            }
        }
    })
}

//passing the selected docs to this function.
saveQueryExternalUser(queryDetails: any, attachments: any[]) {
        let formData = new FormData()
        for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
            formData.append("Document", attachments[i]);
        }
        formData.append("queryData", JSON.stringify(queryDetails))

        return this.httpClient.sampleQueryMgmtPostWithXhr('api/QueryManagementQuery/saveExternalUserQueryDetails', formData);        
    }
```

My Server code also looks simple, Snippet of the server code, where the docs are passed and consumed -

```
 public BaseResponse SaveExternalUserQueryDetails(DTOSaveQueryDetails queryDetails
        , List<DTOQueryDocumentFileFormat> documents)
    {
        BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();

        //Save attachments
            if (documents.Any())
            {
                var isSuccessful = SaveQueryDocuments(queryDetails.QueryHeaderId, documents);
                if (!isSuccessful)
                {
                    response.ErrorMessages.Add("Could not save attachments");
                    return response;
                }
            }
```

I prefer to strip the metadata info of the file in server side either during upload.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There's no magic solution to this - for each file-type that you support you'll need to implement specific code to identify and remove that metadata. e.g. JPEG/JFIF images can have either XMP or EXIF metadata - which different from PNG's metadata - and different from MP3 ID3 tags, or Word Document author-info, and so on...